# How can I get the translated only products with translation from WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency with Rest API?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

The problem is that I get this excerpt of a product from Woocommerce:

```
[
    {
        "id": 73,
        "name": "cBox",
        "slug": "cbox",
        "sku": "",
        "price": "169",
        "regular_price": "169",
        "sale_price": "",
        "on_sale": false,
        "purchasable": true,
        "total_sales": 0,
        "virtual": false,
        "downloadable": false,
        "downloads": [],
        "download_limit": -1,
        "download_expiry": -1,
        "external_url": "",
        "button_text": "",
        "tax_status": "taxable",
        "tax_class": "",
        "manage_stock": false,
        "stock_quantity": null,
        "backorders": "no",
        "backorders_allowed": false,
        "backordered": false,
        "low_stock_amount": null,
        "sold_individually": false,
        "shipping_required": true,
        "shipping_taxable": true,
        "shipping_class": "",
        "shipping_class_id": 0,
        "reviews_allowed": true,
        "average_rating": "0.00",
        "rating_count": 0,
        "upsell_ids": [],
        "cross_sell_ids": [],
        "parent_id": 0,
        "purchase_note": "",
        "attributes": [],
        "default_attributes": [],
        "variations": [],
        "grouped_products": [],
        "menu_order": 0,
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "has_options": true,
        "translations": {
            "de": "73",
            "en": "76"
        },
        "lang": "de",
    }
]
```

You can see the translations, at least the ID's of the translated products. My question is how can I get directly via rest-api only the translated products?

Because with the property "lang=en" it does not work in the url

Answer (score 0):

What does your request look like?

It should work with the lang parameter, you can read more here: https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/using-wordpress-rest-api-woocommerce-multilingual/

Comment: my request: http://(wordpress_link)/wordpress_01/clone/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&lang=en With this request I get this error: 

`{ "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error", "message": "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.", "data": { "status": 401 } }`

If I leave out the property long I don't get this error anymore, then all products are shown to me, but only the ones in German language.